# How to embed icons inside VB.Net application, so they can be used as shortcut icons?

Tags: windows, vb.net, right-click

I am making a single exe application, that is linked in multiple Right-Click menus.

It is VB.Net application, using Net Framework 4.0

Each of those items needs a different icon.

How do I expose icons inside my exe, so they are available in Right-Click menu items and shortcuts without using post-build hackery?

I mention post-build as hackery, cos some anti-virus might not like the change in the signature that comes with messing about with the exe as a post-build step.

### What I tried:

- Adding png and ico versions of icons to My.Resources
- Adding png and ico versions of icons using Project -> Add -> Existing Item -> selecting files
- Using ImageMagick to combine multiple icons in to one ico file

### What I want (example using explorer.exe):

[image]

### What I have:

[image]

Comment: You may have noticed that, in the Project's Properties/Application, you can specify a `.res` file to add Icon and Manifest information to the executable. This is the unmanaged (standard) way. It's *unmanaged*, though, now the executable Resources depend on you, VS won't help you anymore. Read here: [How to embed a manifest in an assembly...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cheller/how-to-embed-a-manifest-in-an-assembly-let-me-count-the-ways). You can, however, add Icons to the `.exe` Resources after the it's built.

Comment: This also has consequences. Read here: [Add multiple icons to a .NET application](https://einaregilsson.com/add-multiple-icons-to-a-dotnet-application/). -- I didn't suggest any of this, just provided some info :) - This can also be useful, depending of what you decide to do or *experiment* with: [Resource-Definition Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-definition-statements?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @jimi So, the best way is to just have a folder with icon files and load them at run-time in app and use those in shortcuts/right-click menu? Only valid way, without "hackery" after exe is built?